# 100% Div Causes Child's Bottom Margin to be Cut Off

Tags: css, margin

I have a #wrapper div that is 100% height. Inside of that I have several content divs, each are displayed as inline-block and have a bottom margin. The problem is that this bottom margin is somehow being collapsed.

The problem can be seen with very simple code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <!-- lots of content here that will fill the browser window -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've created an example which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6tJw/

I have a feeling this is a webkit issue as both Firefox and IE render the page with the proper margin. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me why it works, but this will work http://jsfiddle.net/Y6tJw/2/

Style

```
#wrapper { height: 100%; background: blue; }
#innerwrap { padding-bottom:300px; background: blue;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="innerwrap">
<div id="content">
    <!-- lots of content here that will fill the browser window -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting. I actually already have an innerwrap (required for other functions), so this will require no extra markup! I wish there was a better way, but I'll take it for now! Thanks.

Comment: this is working because the height of your inner wrapper is extending by the amount of padding you are giving and finally this total height is becoming the 100% height.

Comment: right, but why didn't his example work?  To me they should both work.  Not sure what quirk this is avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because you gave your body a height of 100% with the `min-height`. Try giving `height:auto;` this'll work

Comment: And also margin at the end of the body sometimes doesn't work. Some browser sometime omits it.